# yup form validation with formik using regex not working as expected with bangla font input field

Tags: reactjs, regex, validation, formik, yup

I write a **`regex`** code in registration model but when i input in formik form field with bangla font, regex express can't validate `bangla unicode` value.

```
import * as Yup from "yup";
const banglaLang = /^([A-Za-z]|\p{InBengali})$/i;
class RegisterModel {
  /**
   * Model properties
   */
  constructor() {
    this.employeeNameBn = "";
  }

  /**
   * Validator schema
   */
  validator() {
    return Yup.object().shape({
      employeeNameBn: Yup.string()
        .required("user full name (in Bangla) is a required field")
        .matches(banglaLang, "Please type in bangla"),
    });
  }
}

export const Register = new RegisterModel();
```

Comment: Try `const bangLang = /^[A-Za-z\p{sc=Bengali}]+$/u`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Brother I tried your expression, but it's not working. It's only validate single word (English or Bangla) value (e.g. "Kamal" not "Md Kamal Hasan")

Comment: Then just add whitespace pattern to the class, `/^[A-Za-z\p{sc=Bengali}\s]+$/u`

Comment: it works perfectly with only Bangla language validation with this expression  `/^[\p{sc=Bengali}\s]+$/u;` Thanks Brother @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
/^[\p{sc=Bengali}\s]+$/u;
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[\p{sc=Bengali}\s]+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `\p{sc=Bengali}` - a Bengali char
  - `\s` - a whitespace char
- `$` - end of string
- `u` - a flag that allows the use of Unicode property classes like `\p{...}`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V8EW34/1).